# Should Stack Overflow Talent be listed among the rest of the sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, advertising

Well the question's in the title, [Stack Overflow Talent](https://stackoverflow.com/talent/en?utm_source=so-jobs-get-started&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=brand-activation&utm_term=sotob2b-jobs-get-started-find-a-candidate) seems like an obvious candidate to include in the main list of sites on the stack - or perhaps as a side-bar advert. I don't know about the revenue stream here, but the usual off-topic question on meta resulting in links to [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) should include links to those relevant to profit generation, not to mention relevance to the query.

I've only the most [recent missed opportunity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363786/looking-for-a-software-developer) for reference, but I'm sure there are others.

Comment: It's in the footer on every page across the network. And it's not a site, it's part of Stack Overflow. Sites are Q&A only.

Comment: @Catija The framing of the question was ignorant of the structure of the company (and the footer), per-se. I still wonder if the idea may gain traction to increase prominence. Disclaimer: I'm not touting for a part of the action, just a disinterested party who's curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) only includes Q&A sites, which ... makes sense once you see the statistics. Talent has users and traffic, but no questions or answers.

As Catija mentions, it *is* listed in the footer (of nearly every page on the network):

[image]

so it even has a more prominent place than the Q&A sites themselves (for which you need to click on the category first).

We see a lot of off-topic questions by 'lost souls' on Meta Stack Exchange, but most of those are programming problems or homework questions. We rarely see posts like that one, seeking to hire a software developer, for which it would make sense to redirect them to Stack Overflow Talent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (maybe this should be a separate question in itself, but is it possible easily to see stats for similar questions across the network? Not being a member of any of the big sites I've only seen a few of these elsewhere - strikes me as a tricky thing to search for by non-company members as the deletion rate is likely high. The simple fact that I've been a member of meta and various other sites for 7 years plus may not be indicative, since I've never had specific interest in this issue or the footer as written, but on the main list -  whoever gets to the end? It's so long.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. you can search for "Stack Overflow Talent" across the network: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22stack+overflow+talent%22

Comment: Well, yes, I've spent a lot of time on fruitless searches because the precise terms to search for are unknown to me, the questioner in the referenced post perhaps lacked that prior knowledge. Having dated an employee of an employment agency for a couple of years, they tend rather to the generalist than the specialist in their approach to searching for information. Hmm, maybe my argument should be presented in the body of the question, not the comments.